# how can i get my console app to close whenever the esc. key is pressed throughout the app?

Tags: c#, console-application, console.readkey

//Here is a snippet of my code the menu method calls on 2 more methods within, I have tried everything and don't know what code to use or where to put it. thank you guys!!

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {

```
    const double pi = 3.14159265359;
    const string E = "exit";
    const string C = "circle";
    const string R = "rectangle";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        {

            intro();


            {
                while (true)

                menu();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const double pi = 3.14159265359;
const string E = "exit";
const string C = "circle";
const string R = "rectangle";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
    do
    {
        keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
        intro();


        {
            while (true)

            menu();
        }
    }
    while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}
```

Comment: thank you I have implemented it into my system but its gave me a warning saying unreachable code detected with a green line under the:

Comment: while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

Comment: delete while true or post exact code you have